# Determine if a string is available or not in a column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I have a table with fields ID, Name and SubjectID.

In which SubjectID has many values with comma separators, eg. 1,5,6,8

Now if Pass parameter 5 then I want to find all the rows which have 5 in SubjectID.

I used findstring but it is not working .

So how can I achieve this in Sql server 2008.

Comment: If it's a frequent operation I'd advise you to look in to changing your data structure, finding data in the middle of strings is not necessarily a fast operation.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TableName
WHERE   ',' + csvValue + ',' LIKE '%,' + @value + ',%'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e4c81/2)

As an Advice, you need to structure your table into 3-table design assuming that you are like mapping a `Student` into `Subject`. This seems to be `Many-to-Many` relationship.

**Student Table**

- **StudentID (PK)**
- StudentName
- *other columns...*

**Subject Table**

- **SubjectID**
- SubjectName
- *other columns...*

**Student_Subject Table**

- StudentID (FK) and at the same time compound primary key with SubjectID
- SubjectID (FK)

Comment: Great answer J W! This `WHERE` condition would return true for any position of the search string inside the column value - the beginning, the end or anywhere in between. And also good to see the advice that is followed as the best practice in the industry.